# How to Transfer data between different SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to Transfer data from One SQL Server to another SQL Server.

Sql Server Credential

```
 sql server name = Test
 UserName = sa
 Password = test1
```

Another Sql Server Credential

```
 sql server name = Test1
 UserName = sa1
 Password = test12
```

Now i want to transfer data from Server Test to Server Test1, How can i do in store Procedure?

Also i dont wanna use backup file i want to right only store procedure.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Amit Vyas

Comment: It depends on the setup; given the proper scenario, you can address another database using a 4-part naming convention (server.database.schema.object). For a more robust solution, I'd probably consider SSIS.

Comment: @TimMedora Actually i don't know about any process. Can you Please distinguish how can i do??

Comment: See @shibormot's answer...that shows 4-part naming and a linked server. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594328/what-is-the-best-practice-to-transfer-data-between-sql-servers

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup [Linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) for Test server on Test1 server, and then use data from Test server in queries and stored procedures of Test1 server. for example

```
select * from Test.somedb.dbo.SomeTable

exec Test.somedb.dbo.SomeProc
```

or if you want to automatic transfer data from tables on first server to tables on atother, you can use [Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Comment: Is this work if my sql credential is different?

Comment: yes, when you create linked server, you configure credentials for target server

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways you could actually set this up.

1.) Linked Server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

2.) OpenRowSet
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

3.) Replication
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Depending on your needs you need to choose the best one for you.

If you want the data from your second database to be accessable in your original databse, in the same way as it's own data, for queries, stored procedures...etc have a look at Linked Servers.

If you want a one off access to data have a look at OpenRowSet.

If you have the same table on both databases and want to keep that data in sync automatically I would look at Replication.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried  `DTSWizard` ? Its a GUI based tool to do so..